# solidity-coverage : configure to ignore files

Tags: unittesting, solidity-coverage

I have a helper contract that is used only for testing. I don't want it picked up by coverage and showing in coverage results. I want to exclude it somehow.

This link basically says the only option is using the istanbul comments/directives
https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage/issues/17

`/* istanbul ignore file */` as the first line of the contract doesn't work for me.
I've tried a couple of other istanbul directives but no luck.

How to ignore files? (or at least chunks of code)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .solcover.js file and add the files to it.

```js
module.exports = {
  skipFiles: ['Routers/EtherRouter.sol']
};
```

https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#skipping-tests

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to improve 0xCourtney's [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/135643/117046).

From [documentation](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage#config-options) -
Array of contracts or folders (with paths expressed **relative to the contracts directory**) that should be skipped when doing instrumentation.

```
module.exports = {
  skipFiles: ['folder_in_contracts/fileName.sol']
};
```

or file in contracts folder:

```
module.exports = {
  skipFiles: ['fileName.sol']
};
```